# Related post without plugin for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I need some help modifying this script. I am trying to also show related posts by custom taxonomies and custom post types.

```
//* Define custom image size for featured image in Related Posts
add_image_size( 'related', 300, 0, true );


add_action( 'genesis_after_entry_content', 'child_related_posts' );
/**
 * Outputs related posts with thumbnail
 *
 * @author Nick the Geek
 * @url http://designsbynickthegeek.com/tutorials/related-posts-genesis
 * @global object $post
 */
function child_related_posts() {

    if ( is_singular ( ) ) {

        global $post;

        $count = 0;
        $postIDs = array( $post->ID );
        $related = '';
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
        $cats = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );

        if ( $tags ) {

            foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {

                $tagID[] = $tag->term_id;

            }

            $args = array(
                'tag__in'               => $tagID,
                'post__not_in'          => $postIDs,
                'showposts'             => 8,
                'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
                'tax_query'             => array(
                    array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
                                        'field'     => 'slug',
                                        'terms'     => array(
                                            'post-format-link',
                                            'post-format-status',
                                            'post-format-aside',
                                            'post-format-quote'
                                            ),
                                        'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                )
            );

            $tag_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {

                while ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {

                    $tag_query->the_post();

                    // $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
                    $img = genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related' ) );

                    $related .= '<div class="related-post"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . get_the_title() . '</a></div>';

                    $postIDs[] = $post->ID;

                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( $count <= 7 ) {

            $catIDs = array( );

            foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {

                if ( 6 == $cat )
                    continue;
                $catIDs[] = $cat;

            }

            $showposts = 8 - $count;

            $args = array(
                'category__in'          => $catIDs,
                'post__not_in'          => $postIDs,
                'showposts'             => $showposts,
                'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
                'orderby'               => 'rand',
                'tax_query'             => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
                                        'field'     => 'slug',
                                        'terms'     => array(
                                            'post-format-link',
                                            'post-format-status',
                                            'post-format-aside',
                                            'post-format-quote' ),
                                        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                                    )
                )
            );

            $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {

                while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {

                    $cat_query->the_post();

                    // $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
                    $img = genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related' ) );

                    $related .= '<div class="related-post"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . get_the_title() . '</a></div>';
                }
            }
        }

        if ( $related ) {

            printf( '<div class="related"><h3 class="related-title">Related Posts</h3><div class="related-posts-list" data-columns>%s</div></div>', $related );

        }

        wp_reset_query();

    }
}

//* Enqueue and initialize jQuery Masonry script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_masonry_script' );
function sk_masonry_script() {

    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry-init', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/masonry-init.js', array( 'jquery-masonry' ), '1.0', true );

    }

}
```

Here are the post types that I have:

1: post (tags, categories)

2: custom_post_type: (4 custom taxonomies)

3: custom_post_type: (2 custom taxonomies)

4: custom_post_type: (1 custom taxonomies)

I was able to make some adjustments by just looking at the code and was able to get custom post types related posts to show up. However, i am sure that there is someone better than I am out there who can make this work.

Comment: downvted as it is basically a code review request which is usually outside of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, actually if to show me relevant articles you can use plugins

This helps you to reduce a lot of effort

However, as I see, you want to display related articles on how to be able to optimize website loading speed

I do not suggest you use the API functions outside of wordpress, but for me it is a good solution.

I can give you a solution as follows:

- You create a custom field for the post - _title (content is the title of the article)
- You need INDEX for the table wp_postmeta (meta_value field)
- ADD You fulltext for this field

then use the SQL statement (not the wordpress API) to query related articles under the title of the article

Using Fulltext search with the meta_value have relatively good speed.

Wish you success

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this? I looking at the same script and i want to use it on my site as well.